# Swift: View bounces back when raising it for keypad

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, keypad

I am trying to raise the View when a Keypad comes up, but it just bounces back.  If I give `CGRectOffset` a positive value for Y (moving the View down), then it stays.

```
@IBOutlet weak var PPI: MainTextFields!




    var KbHeight: CGFloat!



    //----------------------------------------------



    func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
        let TFMovement = (up ? -KbHeight : KbHeight)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, TFMovement)

        })
    }



    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                KbHeight = keyboardSize.height
                self.animateTextField(true)
            }

        }

    }


    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.animateTextField(false)
    }



    //----------------------------------------------


    // Touch Outside Keypad to leave it
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)



        // For TextField Movement
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        //  For TextField Movement
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        PPI.delegate = self

    }
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `CGRectOffset` in the `keyboardWillShow` function?  I am relatively new to Swift and got this from a tutorial, but just doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: is your view having constraints? if so then changing the frame will never help. You should be changing the view constraints according to what you want your view to become instead of changing the frame which is right away changed back by the constraints defined on that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be because of the Auto-Layout Constraint I had to the Top Margin, so the Constant of that Constraint needed to be changed and the line:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, TFMovement)
```

was not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make left to right background move animation when my viewController loads. Here is what I made in my app:

```
var backgroundImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: 

UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)
UIView.animateWithDuration(20.0, animations: {
backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -700, y: 0, width: backgroundImageView.image!.size.width, height:backgroundImageView.image!.size.height)
})
```

Hope this example helps a bit :)

Try using CGRect, and give it positive y value. This way you will get this rect position in the end of your animation. When keypad has closed, move it back with the y value 0.